# Using both cocoapods and carthage together for different libraries

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, cocoapods, carthage

I installed Alamofire with Carthage, and I found some other libraries that I might want to integrate with my projects too but unfortunately they only support Cocoapods.

So the question is, can I use Carthage for library A and Cocoapod for library B?

Comment: Sure you can - as long as libraries do not share dependencies, you can include them any way you want.. BTW Alamofire can be included via CocoaPods too

Comment: Yea but I've always prefer Carthage when I have a choice :x Then I now come across another library that only supports Cocoapods :x

Comment: The only apparent requirement of Carthage is that the library be built as a framework, is this the problem you are having - projects that do not compile as frameworks?